# How to correctly create a new weighted feature column from 2 opposing features

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-weighting

I have the following dataset:

| Date | ID 1 | ID 2 | ID1avg_rtg | ID2avg_rtg | ID1avg_Importance | ID2avg_Importance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16/7/2022 | 1001 | 1000 | 1.21 | 1.68 | 23 | 68 |

In this dataset I have the average score of electric output samples and the average importance with which this rating came. So rating 1.21 was achieved with importance 23.

The higher the rating the better, but the lower the importance the better. This means that an importance of 1 for example carries much more weight than importance 100. So ID1 scored 1.21 with importance of 23, while ID2 scored a better rating, 1.68 but with a lesser importance (68).

I would like to create a new feature column, called Weighted_rtg. Just multiplying the id1 rating by id1 importance doesn't work, because higher (numerically) importance is less important. But since higher rating is better, I need some kind of mathematical function to create this new column. **Most of my ratings are going to be between the range of 0.5 and 2. So in the new column I would ideally like to keep this range as well, if possible. Importance should also range from 1 to about 200.**

I thought of using the log function, doing 1/log(rating*rank). But I'm not sure this is a good idea.

Are there are better ways or functions to model this new column?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jason. Unfortunately, your criteria are so vague and qualitative that they permit a wide variety of different answers.  If you could be more specific (and quantitative, if possible) then you will greatly increase your chances of getting satisfactory answers.

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t just want to include both original features in a flexible model and let the model figure out how they are related?

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I just saw your comment. I guess it's possible to do that as well, but I wanted to some feature engineering where I know how the column is computed, and that it corresponds to my intuition that higher average rating is better with a larger importance.